# selectSingleNode works but not selectNodes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, selectsinglenode, selectnodes

Javascript:

```
var req=xmlDoc.responseXML.selectSingleNode("//title");
alert(req.text);
```

as expected, returns the text of the first "title" node.

but this

```
var req=xmlDoc.responseXML.selectNodes("//title");
alert(req.text);
```

returns "undefined."  The following:

```
var req=xmlDoc.responseXML.selectNodes("//title").length;
alert(req);
```

returns "2."  I don't get it.  Maybe when I selectNodes it isn't getting the text node inside the title.  That's my guess for now...here is the xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE catalog SYSTEM "catalog.dtd">
<catalog>
<decal>
<company>Victor</company>
<title>Wood Horn Blue Background</title>
<image>
<url>victor01.jpg</url>
<width>60</width>
<height>60</height>
<name>Wood Horn Blue Background</name>
<link></link>
</image>
<price>$15.00</price>
<instock>In Stock</instock>
<notes>no extra info</notes>
</decal>
<decal>
<company>Victor</company>
<title>Wood Horn without Black Ring</title>
<image>
<url>victor02.jpg</url>
<width>60</width>
<height>60</height>
<name>Wood Horn Without Black Ring</name>
<link></link>
</image>
<price>$15.00</price>
<instock>In Stock</instock>
<notes>no extra info</notes>
</decal>
</catalog>
```

thanks

Comment: Basically I want a list of the text in each <title>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

selectNodes returns an array rather than a single node (hence the plural naming of the method).

You can use an indexer to get the individual nodes:

```
var req=xmlDoc.responseXML.selectNodes("//title");
for (var i=0;i<req.length;i++) {
   alert(req[i].text);
}
```

Comment: okay it worked but I had to make it "i<req.length"  Thanks everyone!

Comment: My bad - for completeness it should have req.length. I must have miss-typed. I'll edit now.

Answer (score 5):

`selectNodes` returns an array.

Therefore, when you write `var req=xmlDoc.responseXML.selectNodes("//title")`, the `req` variable holds an *array* of elements.
Since arrays do not have a `text` property, you're getting `undefined`.

Instead, you can write`req[0].text` to get the text of the first element in the array.

Comment: sorry it didn't refresh here that fast.  I want a list of the text in each <title>.

Answer (score 2):

As the method name suggests, `selectNodes` returns a collection (array). You need to loop over them.  Or if you're sure of the structure, grab the first element.